# is it a good way to declare a string field as JSON in gRPC proto?

Tags: json, data-structures, protocol-buffers, grpc

Since it is quiet trouble some in protobuf to define a flexible structure in some scenario.

for example:

```
message Foo {
   int a = 1;
   repeated int a_other = 2;
}
```

In fact, I don't want the service's client to pass the `a` and the `a_other` at the same time.
However in protobuf, we can't put these two fields in `oneof` because the `a_other` is a list field.
So with the above message declared, when we only pass the `a_other` field, the client side cannot tell if the `a` field is actually 0 or not passed by the server.

So I wonder if define a string field for `Foo` like:

```
message Foo {
   string data = 1;
}
```

and both the server side and the client side is agreed to treat the `data` field as a JSON. So the server dumps the primitive data and the client loads it, and they live happily ever after.

But my question is, is it a common practice to do that? And what is the disadvantage of it? (this way drop the type check of course) Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can put the `a` field by itself in an oneof, or use https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md

Comment: `optional` might also work for you (the implementation is effectively the same as a single item `oneof`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566052/11810946). If you want to pass JSON that is an option but you loose some of the key benefits to using protobuf (type safety, `proto` file fully defines interface, code generation etc).

Comment: it looks like the `optional` does not support `repeated` field either. @Brits

Comment: If you want to do this for a repeated field then wrap it in another message (e.g. `message ints {repeated int i = 1;}`) and then use that as an `optional`/`oneof` (basically the approach taken in `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto`).

Answer (score 1):

Repeated fields in `oneof` are generally solved by a wrapper message. In your case:

```
message Foo {
  oneof choose_one_a {
    int a = 1;
    AOtherMessage a_other = 2;
  }
}

message AOtherMessage {
  repeated int a_other = 1;
}
```

It seems you can easily stop there.

However, if you do ever find yourself in the "I want arbitrary JSON here" situation, then you would probably want to consider [`struct.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto)'s `Value` instead of a plain string. `Value` can hold an arbitrary JSON value. If you want to hold an arbitrary JSON *object* (a.k.a., a map) then use `Struct` instead. Types in `struct.proto` are well-known types known to protobuf and when converting a protobuf message to JSON, [they are represented in native JSON form](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json).

```
message Foo {
  google.protobuf.Value a = 1;
}
```

However, before "dropping the schema and swapping to JSON," you should consult [the different ways of handling dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568458/4690866).