# gRPC - Needs equivalent proto syntax Map<String, Object>

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, proto

Need equivalent proto syntax for Map<String, Object>

map<string, object/Value> is failed during the generate phase

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568458/4690866

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an Any or a struct to accomplish this

1. map<string, google.protobuf.Any>
2. Struct https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto#L51

Comment: Let me try, Thanks Asad

Comment: in one of my proto file : map<string, google.protobuf.Any> map = 3; Still I can see issues ...putMap("key", Integer.valueOf(2)) //compilation fails

Comment: @SyedRafi based on how you are trying to use this - i don't think you understand proto properly - use the link in my profile to reach out and I can help mentor you